# Hit test with a radius on a point

Tags: paperjs

In the paper.js framework the following code performs a hit test on the point of a mouse coordinate.

```
function onMouseUp(event) 
{
var hitOptions = {
stroke: false,
fill: true,
tolerance: 2

};  
var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
}
```

What I would like to do is to perform this test within a given radius of the event.point() but I haven't found a way yet.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

I think the way I was setting the options caused tolerance to be ignored. The following code works:

```
var hitOptions = {
fill: true, 
stroke: true, 
segments: true, 
tolerance: 200 
};  
var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
alert(hitResult);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the tolerance options isn't read due to a bug. You can manually change the tolerance by modifying line 3631 (in the nightly).  For example, if you want a test radius of 200 points:

```
tolerance: paper.project.options.hitTolerance || 2
```

to:

```
tolerance: paper.project.options.hitTolerance || 200
```

Comment: I think the bug was in the way I was setting the options.

Comment: You don't need to change the tolerance in the nightly but your answer did get  help me find the bug. Thank you!